# Schengen visa Switzerland from NYC processing time?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens

I am applying for Schengen visa in NYC. I am an Indian citizen residing in NY. How long should it take to get Schengen visa at Switzerland embassy in NY ?

Comment: Have you called and asked ?

Comment: The Swiss embassy is in Washington DC. You probably want the consulate general in New York. You can only apply there, though, if Switzerland is your main destination and you reside in New York, Connecticut, Maine, Massachusetts, New Hampshire, New Jersey, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, Vermont, Bermuda, Puerto Rico, or the US Virgin Islands.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should apply for visa at the Swiss Consulate in New York

https://www.eda.admin.ch/countries/usa/en/home/visa/entry-ch/up-90-days/where-to-apply-schengen.html

> New York (NY), Connecticut (CT), Maine (ME), Massachusetts (MA), New
>   Hampshire (NH), New Jersey (NJ), Pennsylvania (PA), Rhode Island (RI),
>   Vermont (VT), Bermuda, Puerto Rico, US Virgin Islands
>
> must apply at
>
> Consulate General of Switzerland in New York

Regarding the processing time, it says there about 10-15 days.

> Short stay visas (tourists, visitors, business): Complete applications
>   are in general processed within 10-15 days

You can only apply at the Swiss consulate for schengen visa, if

> **The Swiss Visa Desks can only accept applications from persons whose main destination is Switzerland**
>
> 1. If the travel destination includes more than one Member State, the application must be dealt with by the consulate of the main
>      destination. The main destination is understood to be the destination
>      where the applicant intends to spend the longest time or where the
>      main purpose of the intended journey is carried out.
> 2. If no main destination can be determined, the consulate of the Member whose external border the applicant intends to cross first,
>      must deal with the application (point of first entry).